# Same python function giving different output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making a scraping script in python. I first collect the links of the movie from where I have to scrap the songs list. 
Here is the **movie.txt** list containing movies link

> https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-flat-2010
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-night-in-calcutta-1970
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-scandall-2016
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-strange-love-story-2011
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-sublime-love-story-barsaat-2005
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-wednesday-2008
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aa-ab-laut-chalen-1999
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aa-dekhen-zara-2009
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aa-gale-lag-jaa-1973
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aa-gale-lag-jaa-1994
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aabra-ka-daabra-2004
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aabroo-1943
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aabroo-1956
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aabroo-1968
>   https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/aabshar-1953

Here is my first python function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_songs_links_for_movies1():
    url='https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-flat-2010'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = bs(plain_text,"html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('h3',class_='entry-title'):
        href = link.a.get('href')
        href = href+"\n"
        print(href)
```

output of the above function:

```
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/a-flat-2010/pyar-itna-na-kar.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/a-flat-2010/chal-halke-halke.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/a-flat-2010/meetha-sa-ishq.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/a-flat-2010/dil-kashi.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-2016/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/m-s-dhoni-the-untold-story-2016/kaun-tujhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/raaz-reboot-2016/raaz-aankhein-teri.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/akira-2016/baadal-2.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/baar-baar-dekho-2016/sau-aasmaan.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/gajanan-2016/gajanan-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/days-of-tafree-2016/jeeley-yeh-lamhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/tv-shows/coke-studio-pakistan-season-9-2016/ala-baali.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/piya-2016/piya-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/sach-te-supna-2016/sach-te-supna-title.html
```

It successfully fetches the songs url of the specified link.
But now when I try to automate the process and passes a file **movie.txt** to read url one by one and get the result but its output does not match with the function above in which I add url by myself one by one. Also this function does not get the songs url.
Here is my function that does not work correctly.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_songs_links_for_movies():
    file = open("movie.txt","r")
    for url in file:
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = bs(plain_text,"html.parser")
        for link in soup.find_all('h3',class_='entry-title'):
            href = link.a.get('href')
            href = href+"\n"
            print(href)
```

output of the above function

```
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-2016/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/m-s-dhoni-the-untold-story-2016/kaun-tujhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/raaz-reboot-2016/raaz-aankhein-teri.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/akira-2016/baadal-2.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/baar-baar-dekho-2016/sau-aasmaan.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/gajanan-2016/gajanan-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/days-of-tafree-2016/jeeley-yeh-lamhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/tv-shows/coke-studio-pakistan-season-9-2016/ala-baali.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/piya-2016/piya-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/sach-te-supna-2016/sach-te-supna-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-2016/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/m-s-dhoni-the-untold-story-2016/kaun-tujhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/raaz-reboot-2016/raaz-aankhein-teri.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/akira-2016/baadal-2.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/baar-baar-dekho-2016/sau-aasmaan.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/gajanan-2016/gajanan-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/days-of-tafree-2016/jeeley-yeh-lamhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/tv-shows/coke-studio-pakistan-season-9-2016/ala-baali.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/piya-2016/piya-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/sach-te-supna-2016/sach-te-supna-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-2016/ae-dil-hai-mushkil-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/m-s-dhoni-the-untold-story-2016/kaun-tujhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/raaz-reboot-2016/raaz-aankhein-teri.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/akira-2016/baadal-2.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/baar-baar-dekho-2016/sau-aasmaan.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/gajanan-2016/gajanan-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/movies/days-of-tafree-2016/jeeley-yeh-lamhe.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/tv-shows/coke-studio-pakistan-season-9-2016/ala-baali.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/piya-2016/piya-title.html
https://www.lyricsbogie.com/albums/sach-te-supna-2016/sach-te-supna-title.html
```

and so on..........

By comparing 1st function output and 2nd function output. You clearly see that there is no song url that function 1 fetches and also function 2 repeating the same output again and again.

Can Anyone help me in that why is it happening.

Comment: is there 'https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-flat-2010' line in the movie.txt?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is your problem:
* With the first function, you are fetching urls from one url, and get multiples urls in output.
* With the second function, you use the same structure, but with multiples urls as input, so you get even more url as output ?
What is wrong with that or not expected ?

Comment: Yes you are right but when passing multiple urls as input it does not giving right output.

Comment: I have a doubt, does your movie.txt contain multiples line ? Because it should, but it's not what it look like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is happening, you can print the representation of the url read from the file in the `for` loop:

```
for url in file:
    print(repr(url))
    ...
```

Printing this representation (and not just the string) makes it easier to see special characters. In this case, the output gave
`'https://www.lyricsbogie.com/category/movies/a-flat-2010\n'`. As you see, there is a line break in the url, so the fetched url is not correct.

Use for instance the `rstrip()` method to remove the newline character, by replacing `url` by `url.rstrip()`.

Answer (score -1):

I have a doubt that your file is not read as a single line, to be sure, can you test this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_songs_links_for_movies(url):
    print("##Getting songs from %s" % url)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = bs(plain_text,"html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('h3',class_='entry-title'):
        href = link.a.get('href')
        href = href+"\n"
        print(href)

def get_urls_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    return [url for url in f.readlines()]

urls = get_urls_from_file("movie.txt")
for url in urls:
    get_songs_links_for_movies(url)
```